# I want to print the page and make the Background graphics checkbox to be checked by default

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

On print button i am using something like this:

`onclick="window.print();"`

And i have found below pieced of code to make checkbox checked by default:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; /*Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact !important;  /*Firefox*/
    }
</style>
```

It works if the Print options appear without more settings as below:

[image: Without More Settings:]

However it is not working if the Print has more setting and we need to click down arrow button to look Background graphics checkbox inside Options:

[image]

Any idea how it can be checked by default for all browsers type ?

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to achieve by checking this box? Share more inside maybe we could help you fix your real problem.

Comment: The goal is simple, I don't want to miss our background while printing.In that application it is important to have the background every time one tries to print.Some users are not aware of that option and print without checking that check box and it doesn't meet my purpose.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: I'm afraid not :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it traditionally, but in **react-to-print** library you can pass an attribute to print background graphics.

```
printBackground:true
```

You have to pass this where you are defining your content.

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
                    content:()=>your_component.current,
                    pageStyle,
                    onBeforePrint:()=>your_before_print_function
                    printBackground:true
                    })
```

**pageStyle** is CSS that you want to apply when you are printing

**onBeforePrint** function is called just before gathering content for printing by the library, you can close any dialog or open any component depending upon your need.

Call The handle print function when you click your print button.